# Concrete slab on pressure treated lumber

Tags: concrete

We want to cover up a hollow concrete box of 10' x 10' x 10' with concrete slab.
This will be on entrance of our new house.
My builder suggested to lay concrete slab on steel mesh supported by pressure treated timber support. 
Is it a right method of laying concrete slab on hollow box?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It depends what will be the load over the hollow are below but in any case it is not going to be enough to just use steel mesh. You are going to need to place re-bar into the slab as well that has its structure designed by an engineer to provide the proper strength to carry the slab weight plus the load weight over the hollow space.

Keep in mind as well that this slab will need to have some considerable thickness to accommodate the engineered form of the re-bar. It may turn out that the final design involves a thinner slab that is supported by integrally poured in webbing below.

Comment: It is on entrance of house, added a picture..